# I want to stop releasing particles when i keep holding the mouse click for long

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is particle fountain system, I want to stop releasing particles when i keep holding the mouse click. Just should work only for a single click even i click and hold the button for long.

```js
var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    sizes = [
        45
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount () {
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    $d
    .one('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
      clearInterval( timer );
    })
    createParticle( event );
  }, 1000 / 30) 
  
});


function createParticle ( event ) {
  var particle = $('<div class="particle"/>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();
  
  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
    
    
    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + .25,
     transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
     webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
    particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is particle fountain system, I want to stop releasing particles when i keep holding the mouse click. Just should work only for a single click even i click and hold the button for long.

Comment: The text in your final paragraph seems a contradiction: *stop releasing when I keep holding... should work...even ... hold the button*. You want it to stop or to work when holding the mousebutton?

Comment: Is the snippet meant to work? It does not run for me but your idea looks fun so I was hoping to see it in action. If I understand what you need - assuming it is 'stop the fountain when I hold the mouse button down for a set period', then you probably want to use setTimeout() on the mousedown event and clearTimeout() on the mouse up.  In the first you set some global 'halt' variable that your fountain should observe, and on the mouseup you reset it. Also on mouseup you clear the timer in case it did not fire yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake, you have to correct `.one('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave'` to `on` instead of `one`.

And also the element with class `particles` does not exist since you don't have any html code.

Try this:

```js
var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), 
    wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    maxTime = 30,
    sizes = [
            15, 19, 24, 33, 40, 9, 20, 30, 45
        ],

    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2,
    mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount ()
{
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w.
on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d.
on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  
  var counter = 0;
  
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < maxTime) {
      createParticle( event );
    } else {
      clearInterval( timer );
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    
  }, 1000 / 30);
  
  $d.
  on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
  });
});


function createParticle ( event ) 
{

  var particle = $('<div class="particle"/>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 1.0,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 2.5,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime =  (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();
  
  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
    
    
    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + .25,
     transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
     webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
    particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}
```

```css
.particles {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
  <div class="particles">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: Now If you hold down the button for too long then it stops as requested. Change the value of the variable **maxTime** to adjust.

**UPDATE 2:** As asked for by the OP, here is how to add text into the particles:

```js
var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), 
    wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    maxTime = 30,
    sizes = [
            45, 25
        ],

    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2,
    mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount ()
{
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w.
on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d.
on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  
  var counter = 0;
  
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < maxTime) {
      createParticle( event );
    } else {
      clearInterval( timer );
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    
  }, 1000 / 30);
  
  $d.
  on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
  });
});


function createParticle ( event ) 
{

  var particle = $('<div class="particle" id="'+particleCount+'"/>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 1.0,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 2.5,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime =  (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  addRandomOperatorToParticle(particle);
    
  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    "font-size": size / 1.78 + 'px',
    "text-align": 'center',
    "vertical-align": 'middle',
    "line-height": size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();
  
  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
    
    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + .25,
     transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
     webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
    particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}

function addRandomOperatorToParticle(element)
{
    var operators = new Array("+","-","%","x");
    var operator = operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)];
    
    $(element).html(operator);
}
```

```css
.particles {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
  <div class="particles">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that I added a new function `addRandomOperatorToParticle` which does the job, and I also modified the css. You can extend the operator list inside this function. Or rewrite it so that it takes an array as second parameter with all desired operators / texts.

Comment: Thanks! you modified the fountain effect but yes i got what i want . i just needed a halt on mouse click hold.

Comment: i was missing to define that maximum time interval

Comment: Yes sorry for modifying it, I only added a few more sizes. I forgot to reset it to your values at the end. Cool animation btw!

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. I have a query though. May be if you could help that would be my pleasure. I just want to draw some operators on the reasing blocks. Like if +, -, ×, % etc. Also it will be okey of we can draw only single operator. But i really need it to be drawn on fountain blocks.

Comment: Great, Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have one more query though, As we click anywhere on the screen and the fountain works but my goal is to restrict fountain work by clicking on a particular position/object on the screen. For example let's assume place a 150X150px image on the center of the screen and the fountain should work only when i click on the image and no where else. I will appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that shows an approach to using the mousedown to pause effect with a visual indicator of the time delay before the pause action.

```js
var halt = false;   // controls running or stopped animation.

// function to move the red block to the right
function moove(){ 
  var bobEle = $('#bob');     // cache the red block handle;
  var left = bobEle.position().left;  // read the initial left position;
  var moveLoop = setInterval(function(){
    if (halt) { return false}       // when halt is true we abandon animation.
    left = left + 10;               // otherwise we calc the new left position
    if (left > 200 ) { left = 0 };  // and restart if past the end point we decided on
    $('#bob').css({left : left});   // and move the red square.   
  }, 100)                           // we do this every 10th of a sec to give a decent frame rate.
}

// this function changes the display to Run/Stop depending on halt variable.
// we could also use this to set the value of halt.
function showHalt() {
  var status='Run';
  if (halt) { status = 'Halt'}; 
  $('#status').html(status);
}

// The tick, interval and setBar() func control the initial blue bar width, and its countdown.
var tick = 60;
var interval = 6;
function setBar(){
  barEle.show();
  barEle.css({width : tick, visibility: 'visible'});  
}

var barEle = $('#bar');    
var barTimer = 0;

// We use a listener for the document mousedown event to start the bar countdown.
$(document)
  .on('mousedown', function(e){
    // countdown bar  
    setBar();

    // the barTimer function repeats every 50 millisecs to give a pleasing countdown 
    // When tick = 0 we set the halt variable true to stop the red square animation in moove()
    barTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
        tick = tick - interval;
        
        if (tick === 0) {
          clearInterval(barTimer);
          halt = true;
          setBar();
          showHalt();
          return 0;
        }
        setBar();
      }
      , 50
      )
  })

  // If the user lets the mouse button up we let the animation proceed by setting halt=false
  // and stop the bar from animating. We also hide the bar here.
$(document)
  .on('mouseup', function(e){
    clearInterval(barTimer);
    tick = 60;
    halt = false;
    barEle.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    showHalt();
    })
  
// The start button starts the anumation.
$('#btnStart').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  moove();
  showHalt();
})
$('#btnStart').on('mouseup mousedown', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
div span
{
margin: 5px;
}

#bob
{
position:absolute;
border: 1px solid red;
background-color: red;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
#bar
{
display: inline-block;
width:60px;
height: 5px;
background-color: blue;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='info'>Click the Start button to commence, then hold mousedown anywhere on document to pause.</div>
<div id='display'></div>
<div><button id='btnStart'>Start</button><span id='status'></span></div>
<div><div id='bar'></div></div>

<div id='bob'></div>
```